# Magento 2.4.2 stock wrong on productpage

Tags: configurable-product, products, stock, out-of-stock

I have installed magento 2.4.2 community edition as multistore. The configurable products are uploaded with a csv from the supplier.
On the page with all products I get the right message that the products are in stock or not, but on the productpage every items is 0 stock. I can put it in the shoppingcart with backorders disabled.
Something messed up in my sources and stocks.

Now I use only the default stock, I have tried to move the stock to another source and back. Installed magento 2.4.2 and mageplaza advanced again. I checked all the settings from magento and mageplaza business advanced.
When I change the stock in default, it only changes the salable stock.
https://prntscr.com/11qkn0e

What do I have to change to show the stock with the right numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I got to know about this issue, this seems to be a bug in M2.4.2 documented in https://github.com/magento/inventory/issues/3276. The issue itself is still open and there is no quality patch provided just yet in the [official repository](https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/sections/360010506631-Patches-available-in-MQP-tool-).

If you read the thread on the github open issue you will see that some suggest disabling the `Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi` module or use the the replace mechanism to omit this at composer level:

1. cli:
   `bin/magento module:disable Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductFrontendUi`
2. composer:

```json
"replace": {
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-frontend-ui": "*"
}
```

There are also other alternatives suggested there, but you will have to see which one suits your needs best.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, I found a workaround to get the 0 away.

Comment: no problem. did you find it in the link provided above?

Comment: Yes, I used the option to hide the 0 stock. I hope it will be solved in the next release.

Comment: roger that. then please consider marking/ accepting the answer i gave as solution so others can see it too. cheers and good luck!